# What is the true representation of voltage and current for the sinusoidal wave?

Tags: voltage, current

In the Circuit Theory, the book said  the representation of voltage and current in the sinusoidal wave should be

\$v(t)=V_m\sin(\omega t)\$, and \$V_{rms}=\frac{V_m}{\sqrt{2}}\$

\$i(t)=I_m\sin(\omega t)\$, and \$I_{rms}=\frac{I_m}{\sqrt{2}}\$

However, in the Power Transmission and Distribution, the book said  the representation of voltage and current in the sinusoidal wave should be

\$v(t)=V_m\cos(\omega t+\theta_v)\$, and \$V_{rms}=\frac{V_m}{\sqrt{2}}\$

\$i(t)=I_m\cos(\omega t+\theta_i)\$, and \$I_{rms}=\frac{I_m}{\sqrt{2}}\$

So I want to ask, what is the exact representation of voltage and current in the sinusoidal wave? \$\sin\$ or \$\cos\$? Or we can represent them in both \$\sin\$ or \$\cos\$ ?

Comment: They are equivalent, just shifted in time. Plus, the T&D added terms for phase angle separation to make it easier with the math later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some relationships: -

```
cos(wt) = sin(wt + 90°)

sin(wt) = cos(wt - 90°)
```

Take your pick on which you use because \$\theta\$ can be made to be 90° degrees at will.

Comment: @shineele are you done with this now?

Comment: No,first i agree with your answer about cos and sin ,but if  you said because these relation,then  both representation are true,that is ,\$\sqrt{V_m}sin(wt)=\sqrt{V_m}cos(wt+\theta_v)\$,this means that \$\theta_v\$ must be -90 degree and can't be the other number

Comment: @shineele that tallies for your question but it doesn't mean that you can't have this: \$\sin(wt + \theta) = cost (wt - 90 + \theta)\$

Comment: Do you want to say \$sin(wt+θ_s)=cost(wt−90+θ_c)\$,\$ \theta_s=\theta_c-90\$?

Comment: Given that \$\sin(wt) = \cos(wt-90)\$ then \$\sin(wt+\theta) = \cos(wt - 90 + \theta)\$.